# What is the process to load 180 images in this tutorial?

Tags: texturing, materials, workflow

I have a question about what is happening in this Blender tutorial...

**AE『blender 3』 チュートリアル39 Photo Mosaic Animation in Blender EEVEE | Video Editing**

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H8HuC9Us_l8

Could someone please someone explain how this was done?

Up to 3:24 minutes I can follow the steps to create this mosaic below.

[image]

At 3:27 minutes all of a sudden, the planes have 180 different images and I'm lost.

[image]

All I have been able to do is add the same image 180 times.

Thanks Ivan

Comment: Hmmm, that's exactly why I hate sped up tutorials wirhout voice overs... comments are also deactivated so that nobody could ask what happens there  To be honest, I might figure out a a way but I watched it on my mobile where everything is too small to see what's going on. There also seems to be a cut before the images suddenly appear, so I dont think this is done by just one click. I'll rewatch it on a larger screen to find out more.

Comment: no, in the video every plane has a different image.

Comment: @Chris Did I say something else? Or are you referring to Ivan's last sentence in the question? Ivan: I guess when you have the same image 180 times, this is because you use one material (where you select a single image) for every plane. In the tutorial they duplicated the material so that each has its own, then you can load other images for the other planes.

Answer (score 5):

You can enable "Import Images as Planes" add-on, then <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>I</kbd>, <kbd>I</kbd>, select all image files of interest, and select settings (Shadeless / Emit material if you don't want to change the color of the images).

Then Run a Python script:

```py
import bpy
from bpy import data as D

single_width = 1920
single_height = 1200
ratio = 1/1200  # the add-on automatically resizes height to 1
single_width *= ratio
single_height = 1
images_per_row = 10
images_total = 120
rows = images_total / images_per_row  # 12
margin_x = 0.1
margin_y = margin_x


for i in range (120):
    row = i // images_per_row
    col = i % images_per_row
    plane = D.objects[str(i+1)]
    x = (col - images_per_row/2 + .5) * (single_width  + margin_x)
    y = (row - rows/2           + .5) * (single_height + margin_y)
    plane.location.yz = x, y  # use default plane to avoid rotating
```

[image]

Comment: so you should make that tutorial....!  ;)

Comment: I'm not experienced in python, but do I understand it correctly that this creates one plane with all images on it?

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann it creates multiple planes (the behavior of Import Images as Planes add-on), and the script positions those planes. To get a single plane, probably the simplest way is to render an image.

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady Ah okay, couldn't read that script ;) For the desired effect in the tutorial multiple planes are the only way to go.

Answer (score 3):

There might be a smart way do to this easy in Blender, but I don't know it. If you're asking how they did it in the tutorial: they made 180 materials, one for each plane.

Short explanation: the material used for the plane has no way of distributing the images over several planes.

Long explanation: I've watched the interesting parts of the tutorial a few times now, the material that's being created and how the planes suddenly have the images on them.

And when the material is created it only gets the *Image Texture* node, but no image is loaded. So at first this is a "blank" material without any image. There's also no mapping or anything which would help distribute images in any way.

Then there is a cut in the video, because when they switch to rendered view and all the images appear, the material suddenly has an image in the *Image Texture* node. But there is no number next to the material name in the *Shader Editor*, indicating it's a single user material. If all planes used this material there would be a "180" showing - or all planes together are one object.

But since the planes are separated so that each one is a new object, they all need to have individual materials which means, the tutorial skips the part where every plane gets his own material with a new image loaded in.

Comment: Maybe a better idea would be to use one single image and one single material) and just do a uv shifting?

Comment: @Chris Well, as I said there might be smarter ways. I just explained what happened in the tutorial. You can see that each image is separate because there is one opened in the _Image Editor_. And there is also no UV shifting in the tutorial.

Comment: Yeah. That’s why I don’t like that kind of tutorials. And as a beginner you shouldn’t watch sped up tutorials at all…. But even in some „slow“ tutorials „magic“ happens because tutorial maker did cut out too much of his original recording. Happens.‍♂️

Comment: @Chris But what I meant in my answer about a smart way was to somehow import single images as a sequence and distribute them.

Comment: That’s why I followed the question. Would be nice if that’s possible…but I don’t know whether and if …how…

Comment: @Chris Yep, don't like those kind of tutorials either. Even though I'm not a beginner I always find that annoying. And most of the time I hate the music, too 

Comment: And now draw the rest of the owl.

Comment: Lol. Same. And the robotic voiceovers are awful too…

Comment: What?! What owl?! What did I miss?

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady Yes, exactly 

Comment: ok, found a great way. Not "his" way, but if you say "import as planes" and choose multiple images...you get: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pgWSS.png Tadaaaaaaa

Comment: @Chris Don't know it? Google "How to draw an owl" 

Comment: wasn't the original: now draw the rest of the fucking owl!? :))))

Comment: @Chris Maybe you could give that as an answer in a way that it works the way he needs it to achieve what's visible in the tutorial. The tutorial channel seems to be not so very skilled at Blender (it's an AE channel after all), for example resetting the camera by entering every single 0 in each X, Y, Z field for location and rotation...

Comment: I don’t think that this is as he did it… of course you could adapt it. But I would be different from the tutorial. My advice (which nobody wants to hear) would be: search for better tutorials (and there are lots of amazing free tutorials out there)

Comment: If Ivan „just“ wants a solution I would. But I think he wants to follow the tutorial.